# Is there a FLAG_ACTIVITY_**** to bring a previous Activity to front and finish all the others between the stack?

Tags: android, up-navigation

I have currently some Activities in my stack, let's imagine:

A,B,C,D,E.

I am in Activity E and my "up navigation" should bring Activity A to the front and finish (B,C,D).

I am currently working with:

```
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
```

This is nice and Activity A comes back in it's previous state, but (B,C,D) still exist.

Is there a way to correctly finish (B,C,D)?

Note: I am searching to avoid complicated stuff like onActivityResult that would be impossible to deal with in a complicated application structure

Thanks.

Comment: also finish activity E? so only A should be in stack?

Comment: I can easily finish E with finish() as this is the current one. The objective is to bring A to the front (so not to finish it)

Comment: i mean if you want to have only one activity at the time in stack you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is what you need:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Although if you want to reuse the existing instance of Activity A (via `onNewIntent()`) then you might also need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
  case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot accept both answers... THanks for your help.